# SwigPyObject and JSON communication inside python code

Tags: c++, python, json, swig

**Intro.**
I have a C++ application, I use SWIG to launch `GetObjects` and `PutObjects` methods which are defined in python code. `GetObjects` method opens JSON formated file, takes objects from there and returns back them to C++ application. While the `PutObjects` method gets objects from C++ application, opens JSON formated file for writing and stores them over there.

The code is pretty common and uses MyJSONDecode and MyJSONEncode functions to interact between python objects and json dictionaries.

**Now the problem.** 
Swig converts `MyObject` C++ class into python class called `MyObject` located in `abc` module. I use `import abc` statement to use it further in code like `abc.MyObject()`.
`abc.MyObject` is a `SwigPyObject` and it does not have dictionary itself (`__dict__` member).

So I can't iterate through `MyObject.__dict__` inside MyJSONEncode function to build up a dictionary which should be returned by the function and therefore to create a JSON format.

But MyObject has properties, for example url or name and so on. How can I iterate through properties ?

If needed, I will provide you with code. Just let me know. Also I hope, in general, my problem is understood.

Waiting for kind response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the "dir" function to get a list of attributes of an object.

Here is example which grabs all non function user created attributes (called "properties"):

```
import inspect

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1
        self.c = 'a'
    def func(self):
        pass

obj = MyObject()
# Get all the user created attributes for the object
attributes = [d for d in dir(obj)
              if not d.startswith('__')]
# Filter those to get the non functions
properties = [a for a in attributes
              if not inspect.ismethod(getattr(obj,a))]
```